# Copy from textarea to div, preserving linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I've got a `<textarea>` and a `<div>` (with a `<p>` inside).
When entering text into the area, the `<p>` gets updated with the content upon keyUp.

Is there a way to preserve linebreaks (new line) from the textarea and somehow get them to work like linebreaks in the div/p?

Replacing double "new line" with `</p><p>`, is that possible as well? This is close to what a wysiwyg would handle, but don't want that for this, which is a very small project.

---

This is what I've got so far.

```
$(".box textarea").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();  
  $('.box p').text(value);
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$('.box textarea').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    $(".box p").html(value);
});
```

This will replace all the line breaks `\n` in your `textarea` element and replace them all with html `<br/>` tag, so that you can preserve the line breaks in your textarea inside `<p>` tag element also.

**Simple Demo Here:**

```js
$('.box textarea').keyup(function() {
  $(".box p").html(this.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
});
```

```css
textarea,p {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <br/>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

If you can make changes to your css files, then you can also try the below solutions as suggested by *@Explosion Pills*. Even though you will have to still use the jquery code here to add the `textarea` entered text to `p` tag on `keyup` event like:

```js
$('.box textarea').keyup(function() {
  $(".box p").html(this.value);  // replace is not needed here
});
```

```css
textarea,p {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: pre; // <--- This is the important part
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <br/>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Been wandering around this kind of solution for a hour or so, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Xavio Note that this will fail if your textarea contains text with HTML tags (which, presumably, you don’t want want to be interpreted). Granted, you could replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively, but using the `white-space` CSS rule is much cleaner.

Comment: Even worse, if there's any chance that the content of the textarea could be influenced by a malicious attacker, this will open you to HTML injection and XSS attacks. The rule of thumb is, *never* ever mix unescaped user input and HTML.

Answer (score 41):

You probably want to add the CSS rule `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` to `.box p`.  This will display whitespace as-is.

Comment: This is probably the best answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A line-break is a line-break, not a new paragraph, and using css instead of jQuery is always the preferred solution IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest and safest pure jQuery solution:

```
$(".box textarea").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.box p').text(value).css('white-space', 'pre-wrap');
});
```

Of course, if you can add `.box p { white-space: pre-wrap }` to your static CSS styles, then you don't need to inject it with jQuery.

(Also note that [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) also causes multiple consecutive spaces to be preserved, and not to be collapsed into a single space.  If you don't want that, but still want to preserve line breaks, use `white-space: pre-line` instead.)

---

Ps. You should *never* pass unescaped user input to `.html()` (as e.g. the currently accepted answer does), since doing so will cause mangled output if the input contains any HTML metacharacters like `&` or `<`, and can also open you to HTML injection and cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks if the input can ever be influenced by a malicious attacker.

If you absolutely insist on not using the CSS `white-space` property in any form, you will need to first escape any HTML metacharacters in the input before adding `<br>` tags into it.  Probably the simplest and safest way to do that is to let the browser handle the escaping for you, e.g. like this:

```
$(".box textarea").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.box div.output').text(value).html(function (index, html) {
    return '<p>' + html.replace(/[^\S\n]+\n/g, '\n').replace(/\n\n+/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p>';
  });
});
```

This will *first* copy the input text into the target element using `.text()` (which automatically HTML-escapes it) and then modifies the resulting HTML code to remove trailing whitespace from lines, to collapse multiple consecutive linefeeds into paragraph breaks, and finally to replace single linefeeds with `<br>`tags.

(Note that, in order to allow multiple paragraphs in the output, the target element should really be a `<div>`, not a `<p>` element.  Nesting one `<p>` element inside another is not valid HTML, and may not produce consistent results on different browsers.)

Answer (score -2):

Use `string.replace("\n", "<br/>")` to replace any line breaks in your text area to a new line in your page.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ta()
{
taValue = document.getElementById("ta").value;
taValue = taValue.replace("\n", "<br/>");
document.getElementById("tatext").innerHTML = taValue;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ta" onkeyup="ta()"></textarea>
<div id="tatext"></div>
```

Comment: -1: This is just a (needlessly wordy) duplicate of Palash Mondal’s incomplete answer.

Comment: ...and has the same security flaw, too.

Comment: Guys who commented here I do not understand why you see this being bad. It works and if it is a duplicate as you said then pls do give the link of were the so called duplicate is so that this can be honestly flagged and not just based on somebodies proposal or opinion. @RaphaelSchweikert

Comment: Okay I have tested this code and it works. So were is the so called "security flaw" you atlk off? If you mean of the above comment that it is a "duplicate" then pls previde the link to were this duplicate comes from. @IlmariKaronen

Comment: @SeekLoad It was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16165362/1) revision I had been talking about. And the XSS issue is mentioned in the comments of that answer.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert with all do respect but I am still scratching my head failing to see how that revision is the same answer (duplicate) as this one here? As this one here is a "JavaScript" answer and that revision you linked me to is a "query" answer. How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Though I do agree that he when he first posted this, he did include some unnecessary source codes that I edited away.

Comment: @SeekLoad It’s the exact same method: replace `\n` with `<br/>` and (dangerously) set the other element’s HTML. Who cares if one is done with jQuery and the other without, the difference is negligible. What is important is we don’t have lots of duplicate answers but a wide variety so that the discussion on each can center around the pros and cons of each method (see the discussion about XSS). That is literally what downvotes are for on this site.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Just because it is the exact same method does not mean it is the exact same thing or a duplicate as long as it is not the same language. In some cases query may not work and in other cases JavaSript may not work, depending what other codes he may have on the file. So some people may prefer query and other may prefer JavaScript. I personally prefer both depending on the situation.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert EXAMPLE: Right now I am making a page that copies from div to textarea and vice versa, so that it would not matter what box the person writes in, it gives the same result. The problem is that if both codes are in query or in JavaScript then only one is mostly likely to work. To have them "both" working with the same boxes, but against each other, I need to use two different programming systems for example one query and one JavaScript. That way avoiding the two codes from crashing in each other when executing them from the same boxes but the other way around.

Comment: @SeekLoad jQuery is just an abstraction that makes dealing with the DOM a little bit easier/different. But anything that you can do with jQuery you can also do with plain JS (not so much the other way around). And anything you will do in one will work in the other, anything that crashes in one will crash in the other. Anything else you would have to prove to me first. If you really see such a behaviour, please ask a new question about it on this site.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert True "anything that crashes in one will crash in the other". The problem is when they collide and there for crash, then you need two different methods for the two commands so that they will not collide. Its like making two roads with identical path, but yet with two different directions. Because they have two different directions on the same road, they will crash unless they are separated in some way. You could use "function names" to separate them too (that is what I usually prefer), but sometimes "function names" do not separate them as they should and they still collide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138145/discussion-between-raphael-schweikert-and-seekload).

Comment: @Savv after a more rigures test of your code I found a defect. It will only do a break line only on the first line of the text, but it does not repeat it afterwords.