# jQuery break a new line when return is pressed

Tags: jquery

I have some code which prints text that is typed in an input field. I want it so that when return/enter is pressed it breaks to a new line.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8khbz0zc/)

Also the code.

```
    <h3>Your Text:</h3>
    <input id="input" maxlength="50" type="text" name="Text" value="Max. 50 characters">
    <div id="container">
        <p id="text">Your words here</p>
    </div>

    $(document).ready (function() {

$('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#text').html($(this).val());
});

});
```

Comment: you want the cursor goes to the new line if enter is pressed ?

Comment: the text should be going on the new line

Comment: @thinkrite Use the [appropriate element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)?

Comment: which is? That isn't helpful

Comment: There's a link there...

Comment: oh. right. Still that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The exact behaviour that you want, comes with the textarea. Pressing enter takes you to a new line. What is the issue there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textarea` and set `p` specific CSS rule:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#input').keyup(function () {
        $('#text').html(this.value);
    });

});
```

```css
#text {
    white-space: pre-line;
    /* collapse WS, preserve LB */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Your Text:</h3>

<textarea id="input" maxlength="50" name="Text" value="Max. 50 characters"></textarea>
<div id="container">
    <p id="text">Your words here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ah perfect. Thank you. Didn't think it would be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea for multi-line input
input element on default submit form on enter.

Comment: That's not what he wanted

Comment: +1. This solves the *original* problem, unless you have some reason not to use a textarea element? If so, please share it with us.

Comment: @thinkrite if you really need it to still be input i made  other answer that solves problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/26359223/2373547

Answer (score 0):

Change Input type text to textarea it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea instead of input and wrap the .val() value with `<pre>` [element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) like that :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').click(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('#text').html("<pre>" + $(this).val() + "<pre>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Your Text:</h3>
<textarea id="input" maxlength="50" style="resize:none;height:18px;">Max. 50 characters</textarea>
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Your words here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's not that nice to use the `pre` tag. Maybe you could use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165362/3269816

Answer (score 0):

Well, this kind of depends on what you want to do with the content.
If you just want to display multiple lines in the text field, you need a text area, because text fields are meant for single line use only. If you want to insert the text into a text field, you need to add a breakline tag into the text like this:

```
$('#input').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        var newText= $(this).val() + '<br>';
        //doStuff with newText
    }
});
```

for other purposes you might consider to append `'\n'` to the string instead of `'<br>'`. But that really depends on your purposes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the input filed you should add br to the value like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#input').keyup(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(this).val($(this).val() + '<br/>');
    }
    $('#text').html($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Your Text:</h3>

<input id="input" maxlength="50" type="text" name="Text" value="Max. 50 characters">
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Your words here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this prints the <br>, not adding one.

Comment: Well to keep the input field and making new lines that is your only option. Otherwise use textarea :)

Answer (score 0):

New line for each enter

here jsfiddle for You http://jsfiddle.net/8khbz0zc/17/

```js
$('#input').keyup(function(e) {
  $('.text').last().html($(this).val());
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#container").append('<p class="text"></p>');
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Your Text:</h3>
<input id="input" maxlength="50" type="text" name="Text" placeholder="Max. 50 characters" value="">
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">
    Your words here</p>

</div>
```

Comment: why does this copy whatever text has been entered?

Comment: @thinkrite  i thougt that you wanted solution for creating multiple lines, but i edited it for you - clearing line and using placeholder for initial text

Comment: Yes this now works. But I have fonud a simply solution by changing input to text area. thanks though.