# How to use <pre> or something similar to save line breaks to database in react native?

Tags: css, express, react-native

I am learning react native and I have express.js in the backend and react-native in the front end. I have a multiline textInput like this

```
  <TextInput
      style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 22 }}
            multiline = {true}
            numberOfLines = {4}
            ....
  />
```

Then the form is submitted like this.

```
  onQuestionSubmit() {
   fetch('url', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
     databaserow: this.state.blahblah,
   }),
  })
 }
```

When I send stuff to the database and I render it, it comes back as a single line even if I hit "enter" or line breaks several times. What do I have to do in order to preserve the line breaks created while submitting the form?

Comment: Not really solving the issue you presented, but in general I think it is a bad idea to have database input unfiltered posted...

Maybe you can elaborate on what kind of data is being entered within the input?

In HTML one could do the `whitespace: pre-wrap` thinggy as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417527/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-getting-text-from-a-textarea/40417702

don't know how to manage that in react-native though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you use json to pass your data.

The first solution is to escape the "\" so it will be:

```
  onQuestionSubmit() {

   var blah = this.state.blahblah;
   blah = blah.split('\n').map((item, key) => {
     return item+'\\n'
   }).join('');

   fetch('url', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
     databaserow: blah,
   }),
  })
 }
```

then in your `TextInput` defaultValue should be something like:

```
defaultValue={this.state.blahblah.split("\\n").join('\n')}
```

Or another one is to convert the `\n` to something like maybe `<br/>`. So the code should be the same as above, only change the `\\n` to `<br/>`.