# No line break on <p>, value came from textarea

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

The problem is that the value from `textarea`, instead of getting it to next line, it is not working when I used it as at view.

I have this value from a `textarea`

```
TESTING:TESTING
ANOTHER THING:ANOTHER THING
```

But the value in viewing end up like this:

```
TESTING:TESTING ANOTHER THING:ANOTHER THING
```

Using `php` I will get the value.

```
<div>Content</div>
<p><?= $data->content; ?></p>
```

In database the value is same as what I inputted on the `textarea` only the viewing part has a problem. But using it as a `textrea` tends to work.

I wanted the result to be the same as what I input on the `textarea` on the `p tag`.

Comment: so the problem is you need to add a line break between the two strings?

Comment: Try p { white-space: pre-line;}

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417527/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-getting-text-from-a-textarea

Comment: For new line on textarea, you can use `&#10;` *(line feed)* -like this: `<textarea>LineONE&#10;LineTWO</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$string=str_replace(PHP_EOL,"<br>",$_POST["string"]);
echo $string;
```

It will trace and replace php end of line with `br` tag