# How can I retain formatting in a text area input?

Tags: java, angular, forms, rest, formatting

I'm developing an Angular 11 application with a Java backend and a Sql Server database. I just received a request to have certain text area fields within the form retain their formatting after submission (e.g. bullets, indentation, etc). I can't for the life of me find a good resource on doing this, but I know it must be possible.

I need to receive the input in my Angular frontend with its formatting, persist it via json to the Java backend, write it in the Sql Server db, and then retrieve it and display it with the same formatting.

At the moment all I have is a standard text area in an Angular reactive form being sent as usual via json to the backend and the DB.

Does anyone have any wisdom on this? Thank you

Comment: This should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426477/4722965

Comment: @SahilMak thank you, this does help with regard to preserving lines and such. However, I don't see a way to allow bullets to be pasted into these fields; at best, an unordered list shows up as just several lines. Do you know how I can get such characters persisted?

Comment: The only 2 ways I know are to use <div contenteditable="true"> instead of <textarea> or use a 3rd-party WYSIWYG editor (such as CKEditor)