# How to wrap selected text with html element without losing line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I'm using `contenteditable` div as an editor and sometimes I add some code. I need to wrab that code inside `code` element.

to do that I made the next attempt.

**Usage:**

1. add some text with line breaks.
2. select that text.
3. Click the button to wrap the selection.

**The problem:** when I wrap the selection it loses, unwantedly, all line breaks.

```js
function wrapSelection(){
    var selected = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selected != null) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, code(selected));
    };
}

var code = function (S) {
    var str = "<code>" + S + "</code>";
    return str;
};
```

```css
#design_view {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="wrapSelection()">Select and Click</button>

<div contenteditable id="design_view">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `style='white-space: pre-wrap;'` to your `<code>` element

code function would become:

```
    var code = function (S) {
        var str = "<code style='white-space: pre-wrap;'>" + S + "</code>";
        return str;
    };
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426477/7061680) for a more in depth explanation